# Why is the path "/C:badfile" sometimes not being caught by ASP.NET custom error handling?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, configuration

I've got a bit of an odd situation that recently came up in a security scan and I'm having trouble explaining it. In short, the following URL always returns HTTP 400 and a YSOD:

http://www.mypal4me.com/C:badfile

This site is ASP.NET 4 and is hosted on MaximumASP under IIS7.5. This site is configured with custom errors turned ON and a default redirect page. This is evidenced by causing request validation to throw you off to the error page: http://www.mypal4me.com/?%3Cscript%3E

The only way we've found to send this request off to the custom error page is to add an `<error statusCode="400" path="/error.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />` entry under system.webServer.httpErrors in the web.config (obviously this hasn't been done on the site above but has on other MaximumASP sites).

So my question is twofold:

1. Why is this request not being caught by the usual .NET error handling and the custom error page served as a result?
2. Why do I only see this happen at MaximumASP - I can't reproduce an HTTP 400 with that pattern in any other IIS/ASP.NET environment.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s57a598e.aspx

> ASP.NET 4 also enables you to configure the characters that are used
>   by the URL character check. When ASP.NET finds an invalid character in
>   the path portion of a URL, it rejects the request and issues an HTTP
>   400 (Bad request) status code. In previous versions of ASP.NET, the
>   URL character checks were limited to a fixed set of characters. In
>   ASP.NET 4, you can customize the set of valid characters using the new
>   requestPathInvalidChars attribute of the httpRuntime configuration
>   element, as shown in the following example:

Comment: Good pointer, but that that doesn't explain why the custom error page wouldn't be surfaced. The ":" character is in the default set of requestPathInvalidChars values and a normal app throws HTTP 400 and loads the custom error page when the colon is requested. In fact making a request for http://www.mypal4me.com/: throws an HTTP 500 so obviously the handling is differing based on more than just a single character.

Comment: Have just used Tamper Data in firefox to see the HTTP flow - http://www.mypal4me.com/C:badfile returns a 400 error (not 500).

Comment: Yep, agreed, the "C:badfile" pattern thorws 400, what I'm saying is that a request for http://www.mypal4me.com/: (just a colon after the URL), is throwing a 500 so what's causing the different response from MaximumASP? In a local test environment I get 400 for each and custom errors is invoked for each.

Comment: should be mypal4me/: (with the slash)

Comment: Should be 400 though. Misconfiguration on MaximumASP end? It would be nice to check the logs to see if the error returned is actually 500.19  http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2008/02/18/what-to-expect-from-iis7-custom-error-module.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's likely request filtering, specially it doesn't like the C: bit, fearing that it is a directory travesal attack of some sort. Many webhosts security settings will block suck a url.

A most likely guess at the the product in use is UrlScan, http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/473/using-urlscan

Because this filtering runs at a much lower level in the call chain, the request itself is never passed to your asp.net application process (As many of the attacks that are mitigated are designed to trick IIS into returning files outside your application folder). Thus any application defined error routines won't see it, however an IIS error page (which is what your configuring via webc.config) will be triggered.